# Make Google stop sending 'new sign in from ...' emails

Tags: gmail, notifications

I get at least two emails from Google every time I sign in to my account and I want it to stop.

I tried changing the notification settings in Gmail, but they're still coming and they're useless.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching this I've seen others have this issue but no solution was presented.  One "fix" would be to simply put a filter on your Gmail account that deletes any email that has the title of the email that is bothering you.  It's not the perfect solution but it might do until you find something that is more palatable.

Comment: Don't create such filters, it will get your Google account blocked.

Comment: Not only I created that filter, I also marked the message as spam, and then I went to the spam folder to mark it as phishing because that's Google we're talking about. Then I signed in again to test. The filter deleted it successfully, yay. AND THEN I WENT THERE AGAIN AND MARKED IT AS SPAM AND PHISHING AND THEN I SIGNED IN AGAIN AND THEN-
I mean, this is still the correct answer because it disregards Google's interface, known for making solutions stop working over time. Also, if you can and don't mind, disable notifications from Google Play Services (not Google Play Store) in your phone.

Answer (score 10):

It's there but is a little hidden. Log in to your Gmail mailbox, scroll to the very bottom of the page and find the "details" button. Click on it and then in the pop-up window change "Alert preference: Show an alert for unusual activity".

Comment: Is this answer still available? After clicking Details, I can't follow.. no such thing Alert or change options..

Answer (score 0):

We strongly advise leaving alerts on so you can hear about suspicious activity on your account. If you still want to disable alerts, follow the steps below.

Note: It takes about a week for alerts to get turned off. This is because Gmail wants to confirm it's you that's turning them off, and not someone else who might have access to your account.

On your computer, open [Gmail](https://www.gmail.com).
In the **bottom right**, click ***Details***.
At the bottom of the page next to "**Alert preference**," click ***Change***.
Select **Never show an alert for unusual activity**.